# how to show the content of an xml file without knowing how many nodes are in that file

Tags: android, xml, gallery

I am working on an app that is suppose to store a photo and a couple of strings a few times a day and then show them. The photo and strings are stored in an xml (photo's path not the actual data) and I want to read from that xml file and show them. the problem is that I don't know exactly how many instances of data will be in the xml file so I can't prepare a set number of Photos and textViews In advance. I also would like to show them all in a scrollable way of some sorts , like shown in the gallery.

the real question is pretty much what is the best way to show the data in the xml file without knowing exactly how many node are in the file.

Comment: What do you expect it to look like. If it should be a list where each item is displayed after each other you can implement a ListAdapter with different ViewTypes.  How to do this is explained here `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row`

Comment: wow ... yeah that was the general idea , i was thinking more about placing a few imageviews and textviews programatically but that would be fine after I learn it , thanks.